# How do I pass in component from parent to chlid and the child pass in field to the components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I pass in component from parent to child and the child pass props to the components?
how do I pass in onCloseModal in the child component? my createComponent is dynamic, createProduct, createCategory this is why I have to do it like this.

Parent Component

```
export class ProductList extends Component {
  return (
     <PageList
        createComponent={<CreateProduct/>}
      />
  )
}
```

Child Component

```
export class ProductList extends Component {
  onCloseModal = () = {}
  return (
    <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} >
      {/* <CreateProduct onCloseModal={this.onCloseModal}/> */}
      { this.props.createComponent } // how to pass in closeModal function?
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: You could use React.cloneElement. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

Comment: i just read cloneElement. Is it possible to give me an example?

Comment: In your case it would be something like React.cloneElement(this.props.createComponent, { onCloseModal: this.onCloseModal })

Answer (score 0):

Let me write the answer here.

Parent Component

```
export class ProductList extends Component {
  return (
     <PageList
        createComponent={<CreateProduct/>}
      />
  )
}
```

Child Component

```
export class ProductList extends Component {
  onCloseModal = () = {}
  return (
    <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} >
      { React.cloneElement(this.props.createComponent, { onCloseModal: this.onCloseModal }) }
    </Modal>
  )
}
```